# How to flag unused imports and fail the build in Android

Tags: android, gradle, lint

How do I catch "unused imports" in Java/Kotlin in an Android project? I have this configuration:

```
subprojects { subp ->
    afterEvaluate {
        android {
            lintOptions {
                baseline file("${subp.projectDir}/lint-baseline.xml")
                abortOnError true
                warningsAsErrors true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And no lint.xml hoping it will use default.

It is able to flag and fail the `lintDebug` task, say, if I use an older dependency in Gradle file but not when I have unused import in a Java/Kotlin source file.

I tried adding this lint.xml but got an error saying unknown issue id:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lint>
    <issue id="UnusedImport" severity="error" />
</lint>
```

How do I flag unused imports and fail the build? Or should I use `ktlint` for this?

Gradle version 7.3.3.